# JavaScript: сравнение значений

Tags: php, javascript

Некоторое время назад столкнулся с глупой ошибкой, которое привело к багу:

```
var idStart = $('#start').val().split('_')[1]; // получаем порядковый номер дня в году
var idEnd = $('#end').val().split('_')[1]; // получаем порядковый номер дня в году

for (var j = idStart; j <= idEnd; j++) {

}
```

Загвоздка в том, что `idStart` и `idEnd` получались строками, что привело к не ожидаемым результатам: `"6" > "12"` ,т.е. в цикл он даже не заходил. Решил эту проблему переводом в int idStart и idEnd.

После этого случая больше начал задумываться над операторами сравнения и типами.

**Вопрос:** Сравнивая значение с числом, надо ли его переводить в int? И в этом случае сравнивать по `===` или `==`? **Как вы пишите такие сравнения?**

```
if (parseInt(settingType) === 2) {}
```

Я конечно понимаю, что везде и всегда не стоит переводить, отсюда **попутный вопрос:** В каких случаях этого не стоит делать (или вы так не делаете)?

К примеру если есть собственная функция, которая *по идеии* возвращает число, достаточно ли будет сравнивать ее с `===`?

Насколько удобный код для восприятия другим разработчикам получиться?

*p.s. думаю это и к php относится.*

Comment: [Преобразование типов в JS](http://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion)

Comment: Можно использовать более короткую записать. Вместо "parseInt(settingType)", "+settingType".

Comment: `===` как раз проверит тип:

    > "1" == 1
    true
    > "1" === 1
    false